# Close tabs in pidgin conversation window

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, pidgin

How to close several tabs in a pidgin conversation window from a script (some `#general` and `#nickserv` tabs). I tried using `xdotool` and `devilspie` but no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Pidgin's DBus API to close a conversation. See [Pidgin's DbusHowto](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto). The following Python code closes all conversation windows with name matching the `to_close` list. (I tested this with IM usernames, but not with IRC chatroom names, so it may require some additional tweaking for your purposes.)

```
to_close = ["#general", "nickserv"]
for conv in purple.PurpleGetConversations():
    if purple.PurpleConversationGetName(conv) in to_close:
        purple.PurpleConversationDestroy(conv)
```

Put the following at the top of your Python file to initialize the `purple` object for communicating with Pidgin/Finch over D-Bus (from the [DbusHowTo](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dbus
import sys

# Based off http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/DbusHowto
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService",
                     "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")
```

For those of you who don't like Python, here's the same thing rewritten in `sh` using `purple-remote` (note that `for arg` iterates over the arguments to the script):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Note that the result of sed here is a string like "(1234) (5678)".
for conversation in `purple-remote PurpleGetConversations | sed 's/^.*[[]//' | sed 's/].*$//' | sed s/dbus.Int32//g | sed s/,//g`
do
    conv_name=`purple-remote "PurpleConversationGetName$conversation"`
    for arg
    do
        if [ "$arg" = "$conv_name" ]
        then
            purple-remote "PurpleConversationDestroy$conversation"
        fi
    done
done
```

I am completely unsure how brittle that pipeline of `sed`s is, though. The Python seems much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much once again! I've said is wrong. English is not my native language. I'm rewrite your early code to the bash. I'm sorry for the trouble. P.S. Your code is better than my.